# Bin a vector by width

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector of a continuos variable. For example:

```
x <- c(0.9000000,  1.2666667,  4.0000000,  5.7333333, 19.7333333, 35.7666667, 44.0000000,  4.4333333,  0.4666667,  0.7000000,  0.9333333,  1.0000000,  1.0000000,  1.0000000,  1.2000000,  1.2333333, 1.2666667,  1.4333333,  1.7000000,  4.0666667,  1.9000000,  2.1000000,  0.9333333,  1.2666667,  3.7333333,  0.9333333,  2.7666667,  3.1333333,  3.9333333,  5.0333333,  6.0666667,  8.2333333)
```

I want to bin this vector by width (equal number of values) in three groups (low, medium and high values).
So the `low` group would have the third lowest values of all the total.

Then I want to group the low and medium bins so I would have one categorical vector that would have `Not high` subjects, which would be the 66% lowest, and High, which would be 33% highest.

I've checked and I couldn't find any predefined function to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` to split and label a numeric vector. Essentially, you are looking for a single break point equal to the value that is 2/3 of the way along the ordered values of `x`, so you can do:

```r
break_point <- sort(x)[round(2 * length(x)/3)]

break_point
#> [1] 3.733333
```

Anything above 3.733333 will be 'high'. So we can do:

```
y <- cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, break_point, Inf), labels = c('not high', 'high'))
```

If we put this in a data frame with `x`, you can see `y` appropriately labels the highest values:

```r
data.frame(x, y)
#>             x        y
#> 1   0.9000000 not high
#> 2   1.2666667 not high
#> 3   4.0000000     high
#> 4   5.7333333     high
#> 5  19.7333333     high
#> 6  35.7666667     high
#> 7  44.0000000     high
#> 8   4.4333333     high
#> 9   0.4666667 not high
#> 10  0.7000000 not high
#> 11  0.9333333 not high
#> 12  1.0000000 not high
#> 13  1.0000000 not high
#> 14  1.0000000 not high
#> 15  1.2000000 not high
#> 16  1.2333333 not high
#> 17  1.2666667 not high
#> 18  1.4333333 not high
#> 19  1.7000000 not high
#> 20  4.0666667     high
#> 21  1.9000000 not high
#> 22  2.1000000 not high
#> 23  0.9333333 not high
#> 24  1.2666667 not high
#> 25  3.7333333 not high
#> 26  0.9333333 not high
#> 27  2.7666667 not high
#> 28  3.1333333 not high
#> 29  3.9333333     high
#> 30  5.0333333     high
#> 31  6.0666667     high
#> 32  8.2333333     high
```

And you can see that approximately 2/3 of the cases are 'not high' and 1/3 are 'high':

```r
table(y) / length(x)
#> y
#> not high     high 
#>  0.65625  0.34375
```

You can't have exactly 2/3 in the 'not high' group because your vector is length 32, which isn't divisible by 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `quantile()`:

```r
y <- ifelse(x < quantile(x, 2/3), "not high", "high")

proportions(table(y))

#     high not high 
#  0.34375  0.65625
```

Comment: Very nice use of `ifelse` here Darren.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `santoku::chop_equally()`:

```r
library(santoku)
chopped <- santoku::chop_equally(x, 3, labels = c("low", "medium", "high"))
data.frame(x, chopped)
            x chopped
1   0.9000000     low
2   1.2666667  medium
3   4.0000000    high
4   5.7333333    high
5  19.7333333    high
6  35.7666667    high
7  44.0000000    high
8   4.4333333    high
9   0.4666667     low
10  0.7000000     low
...
```

You can then regroup the factor (if you want to keep the low/medium/high version):

```r
library(forcats)
chopped2 <- forcats::fct_collapse(chopped, 
                                    "High" = "high", 
                                     other_level = "Not high"
                                  )
data.frame(x, chopped2)
            x chopped2
1   0.9000000 Not high
2   1.2666667 Not high
3   4.0000000     High
4   5.7333333     High
5  19.7333333     High
6  35.7666667     High
7  44.0000000     High
8   4.4333333     High
9   0.4666667 Not high
10  0.7000000 Not high
...
```

Alternatively, if you only want the "High"/"Not high" version, use
`chop_quantiles()`:

```r
chopped2 <- santoku::chop_quantiles(x, .66, 
                                    labels = c("Not high", "High"))
data.frame(x, chopped2)
            x chopped2
1   0.9000000 Not high
2   1.2666667 Not high
3   4.0000000     High
4   5.7333333     High
5  19.7333333     High
6  35.7666667     High
7  44.0000000     High
8   4.4333333     High
9   0.4666667 Not high
10  0.7000000 Not high
...
```

You say you want to bin by "width (equal number of values)". The above bins by equal number of values, i.e. 1/3 in each of the 3 categories. If you want to bin by width, i.e. into equal-width intervals, use `santoku::chop_evenly()`:

```r
chopped3 <- santoku::chop_evenly(x, 3, labels = c("low", "medium", "high"))
data.frame(x, chopped3)
            x chopped3
1   0.9000000      low
2   1.2666667      low
3   4.0000000      low
4   5.7333333      low
5  19.7333333   medium
6  35.7666667     high
7  44.0000000     high
8   4.4333333      low
9   0.4666667      low
10  0.7000000      low
...
```

Note: I am the santoku package maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found in the R documentation, may help?

bin(x,bin)

About bin:

" ... use "cut::n" to cut the vector into n equal parts, b) use "cut::a]b[" to create the following bins: [min, a], ]a, b[, [b, max].."

Using library fixest
https://rdrr.io/cran/fixest/
Though this is only for integers I checked, sorry.

Source: https://rdrr.io/cran/fixest/man/bin.html

Answer (score 0):

As @Ishan_Tomar mentions, you can use the [`bin`](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/reference/bin.html) function from the `fixest` package.

For numbers, the syntax is `bin(x, "cut::a]b[")` with `a`, `b` (etc) numbers or percentiles followed by an open or closed square bracket (please note that the function `bin` is more general than that).

In your case, you want to create two groups, the first containing 66% of the data. Then you can write `"cut::p66]"` (p66  means the 66th percentile) which will create two groups: `[p0, p66]` and `]p66, p100]`.

Then to give custom names, you can simply add them in the vector, as follows:

```
# You can use the bin function:
x_bin = fixest::bin(x, c("cut::p66]", "Not high", "High"))

# Check it worked
table(x_bin)
#> x_bin
#> Not high     High 
#>       21       11
```